# use **similarity transformation** to find the matrix $ \ B \ $ with respect to the basis $ \ \{(1,2) , \ (3,5) \} \ \ of \ \ \mathbb{R}^2 $ .

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear operator $ \ T(x,y)=(5x,x-y) \ \ on \ \ \mathbb{R}^2 $ .  Find the matrix $ \ A \ $ of  $ \ T \ $ relative to the **standard basis** on $ \ \mathbb{R}^2 \ $ . Then use **similarity transformation** to find the matrix $ \ B \ $ with respect to the basis $ \ \{(1,2) , \ (3,5) \} \ \ of \ \ \mathbb{R}^2 $ .

**Note:** The answer is given as $ B =\begin{pmatrix}-29 & -56 \\ 17 & 33 \end{pmatrix} $

**Answer:**

I have found $ \ A= \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $ .

Now $ \ B=P^{-1} AP \ $  ,

where $ \ P \ $ is the transition matrix from the basis $ \ \{(1,2) , (3,5) \} \ $  to the basis $ \ \{(1,0) , (0,1) \} \ $.

Now calculating I got ,

$ \ P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 \\ 2 & 5 \end{pmatrix} $

Thus,

$ \ P^{-1} =\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 2 \\ 3 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $

Hence ,

$ B=P^{-1} AP = \begin{pmatrix}-5 & 2 \\ 3 & -1 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-27 & -79 \\ 16 & 47 \end{pmatrix} $
 $

**But the answer does not match with the given answer .**

**Was my calculation and appoach right ?**

If not then how to solve the problem ?

**Is there any help ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a "silly" minor  mistake $$P=\left(
\begin{array}{ll}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you use that then $$ P^{-1}AP=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -5 & 2 \\
 3 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -29 & -56 \\
 17 & 33 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Both you and your textbook are wrong.  The correct answer seems to be 
$$
B = \pmatrix{-28&-81 \\ 11 & 32}
$$
As computed [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Inverse%5B%7B%7B1,3%7D,%7B2,5%7D%7D%5D*%7B%7B5,0%7D,%7B1,-1%7D%7D*%7B%7B1,3%7D,%7B2,5%7D%7D). Your mistake is that you incorrectly computed $P^{-1}$; the $2$ and $3$ should be switched.